# Raspberry Pi One Touch Audiobook *Updated*

Tags: raspbian, debian, linux

I am looking for anyone to help me out. I am trying to build [this](http://blogs.fsfe.org/clemens/2012/10/30/the-one-button-audiobook-player/) for my blind grandmother for Christmas.

**Update, since I couldn't get it to work I switched to this guys update python script, which can be found [here](https://github.com/vonProteus/RPi-OBABP) but I am having the exact same problem with both scripts!!

I have everything installed and put together.  When I run the script the LED blinks a few times, so I am assuming it is setup correctly, however when I insert the usb drive it does not store the audio book on the sd card or start playing.  I can't figure out why??

If anyone could please help me out and tell me a step by step process, I would really appreciate it! I would even being willing to pay a fee if anyone helps me figure it out. It would really mean the world to me so I could help my Grandma enjoy life in the nursing home.

Comment: This is when I start the scripted: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rr6fup7g6sh7g8/2012-12-12%2020.05.35.jpg

This is when it tries to extract the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2dzsg6frveax88/2012-12-12%2020.06.49.jpg

Answer (score 4):

Ive had a quick look at the code for the project (both the original and the updated one on github) and the trigger for it uploading the audio files to the sd card is the existance of a device called "1GB".

In the original code,

```
device = checkForUSBDevice("1GB") # 1GB is the name of my thumb drive
```

calls the `checkForUSBDevice` function to check if the a USB disk exists, which it then uses to find the correct device, if it doesn't find a device it loops and then tried again.

Have you changed this line to equal the name of your USB disk or have you renamed the name of your usb disk to be "1GB"?

Comment: Did this solve your problem, Dan? If so, you should mark this answer as *accepted*.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this project. But having compiled a few things myself on the Raspberry Pi, I'd suggest you that you install the packages the guide mentions.

The following is the list of packages

- mpd (music player daemon)
- mpc
- mpd-python
- pyudev (for USB access)

Then to install them, type the following in Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install mpd
sudo apt-get install mpc
sudo apt-get install mpd-python
sudo apt-get install pyudev
```

If the packages are found, then install them. Normally it will ask you for a Y/n response. If the packages are not found, then search the internet for "debian install [name]".

Shout if you run into issues, will try help you out.

Comment: Hey Vincent.  Ok so I got the script to run, now my problem is getting the audio file to auto transfer to the SD card.  It is suppose to be automatic but when I insert it nothing happens.  Do you know what this could be?

Comment: Is the Python script running? Without being there I cant tell you exactly. But is the Python code running?

Comment: Here are some pictures of what is happening, maybe this will help.

This is when I start the scripted:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rr6fup7g6sh7g8/2012-12-12%2020.05.35.jpg

This is when it tries to extract the file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2dzsg6frveax88/2012-12-12%2020.06.49.jpg

Comment: Hmmm really not sure, the python code is running. The new code seems to be quite straight forward. Also I dont see anything strange in the screen shots. I reckon you should contact the dev.

Comment: I've tried to contact him, no response.  For some reason now the file/mp3 is saving to the Pi, but it won't play.  I just don't know what to do, every time I get pass one hurdle another pops up.  I want to give up but I have invested so much time already and I really would like to make my Grandma happy for Christmas.

Comment: Can you navigate to `/mnt/usb/`? In your screen shot it says that it does not exist. Also have you tried playing music on the RPi, to confirm that the audio does work?